Extract multi-part rar using file manager onnly extracts first part
When using file manager to extract a multi-part rar, only the first part gets extracted.  IR, you have 6 1GB rar files, to make a 6GB archive, only the first 1GB file will be extracted.  Thus is different from file manager on my Centos or AlmaLinux box.  Is there anything special that need to be done to get it to extract multifile archives?
